# Code not executed when trying to connecting to WSDL webservice

Tags: java, multithreading, wsdl

When trying to use a webservice, a NullPointerException is thrown, and expected log statements are missing in the application's log.

I get a NullPointerException in the following code:

```
public void useWebservice() {
    initEndpoint();

    try {
        port.usefulFunctionWebserviceProvides(); // NullPointerException is thrown here!
    } catch (javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException ex) {
        log.error("Something went wrong making a request to the webservice");
    }
}
```

The initEndpoint method looks like this:

```
private volatile Webservice service = null; // instance variable
private WebservicePort port = null; // instance variable

private void initEndpoint() {
    String username = "username"; // Loaded from a properties file
    String password = "password"; // Loaded from a properties file

    LoginResponse loginResponse;

    Webservice theService = service;
    if (theService == null || port == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            theService = service;
            if (theService == null) {
                try {
                    log.info("Initializing Endpoint (service & port)"); // This line appears in the log
                    service = new Webservice();
                    port = service.getWebservicePort();
                    final String wsdlUrl = properties.getProperty(WSDL_URL, WSDL_DEFAULT_URL);
                    ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, wsdlUrl);
                    log.info("EndpointAddress set");

                    LoginRequestType loginRequest = new LoginRequestType();
                    loginRequest.setUsername(username);
                    loginRequest.setPassword(password);
                    loginResponse = port.login(loginRequest, null, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    try {
                        log.info("re-Initializing Endpoint (service & port)");
                        // Try to connect to the webservice using a fallback URL
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        log.error("Couldn't connect to webservice");
                        service = null;
                        throw new CustomException();
                    }
                }

                if (loginResponse == null) {
                    service = null;
                    throw new CustomException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

None of the info logging is printed to the log file except for the log message "Initializing Endpoint (service & port)".

I don't understand how the port variable can be null in the useWebservice method. I also expect to see either "EndpointAddress set" or "re-Initializing Endpoint (service & port)" in the log file. But neither are printed to the file.

The code has worked fine before, but has started to give problems after being moved to a new project and used as a dependency.

Comment: And you're positive it's `port.usefulFunctionWebserviceProvides();` that causes the exception?

Comment: Yes, it is the first line in the NullPointerException stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been identified, it was a missing dependency. Because of that an error was thrown when the code tried to initialize the port. The catch block only catches exceptions so that code was never executed. If we caught throwable for example we would see the log statements from the catch block.

PS: Initializing the port object as it is done in the initEndpoint method in the question is NOT thread safe! The port needs to be initialized for each request.